# Realm java Date/timestamp is outside valid range

Tags: realm

Hi i'm writing an andorid app using Realm.  I'm downloading some json data containing a list of project from our server and save the result to Realm, but i'm been encountering a bug with

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Date/timestamp is outside valid range
        at io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.setDate(UncheckedRow.java:201)
        at io.realm.ProjectRealmProxy.setExpiry(ProjectRealmProxy.java:92)
        at io.realm.ProjectRealmProxy.copy(ProjectRealmProxy.java:238)
        at io.realm.ProjectRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(ProjectRealmProxy.java:229)
        at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:123)
        at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1565)
        at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealm(Realm.java:1116)
```

The issue occurs when i'm try to save a project with a expiry date of 2040-11-30.  Does anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: How did you create your Date from JSON? If you are using `date.setYear(2040)`, you will get some date which is out of range. If you really want to use deprecated `setYear`, try `date.setYear(2040-1900)`.

Comment: I'm getting a date string which I convert to Date using SimpleDateFormatter, but as soon as I call .setDate(date) on the realm entity, the error occurs

Comment: Would you please check before you call `.setDate(date)`, what is the year value of the date is?

Comment: before I call .setDate(date), it's null, the project object is just initialized, also  call setDate on more recent date is fine, like setDate(new Date()) does not produce any exception

Comment: for the time bean i'm turning date to a long and store the timestamp

Comment: I mean what is the value of `date` you passed to the `setDate(date)`. It is should be the result after you called the `SimpleDateFormatter` and please check the converting result. I really doubt you didn't get the expected result from `SimpleDateFormatter`.

Comment: No, I think your code is fine. There is a limitation of the Date here. The max date here is 2038 Jan 19...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82769/discussion-between-beeender-and-charlie-wu).

Answer (score 3):

There is a limitation of Date in Realm-java right now, see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#general

> The dates are truncated with a precision of one second. In order to maintain compatibility between 32 bits and 64 bits devices, it is not possible to store dates before 1900-12-13 and after 2038-01-19.

And there is a [opened issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/833) tracking this on github.

Comment: If you either need better precision or wider range, the best workaround is to store your date/timestamp as a `long` instead of `Date`.